# How to add new Customer in ZOHO INVOICE using API? I use the Following POST methode to create the new Customer..But i wont Work

Tags: java, zoho

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/contacts?authtoken="ur_token"&organization_id="ur_org_id");
    StringEntity params =new StringEntity("JSONString={\"contact_name\":\"company_name\",\"age\":\"20\"} ");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    System.out.println(response);

    // handle response here...
}catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

How do you add a new Customer in ZOHO INVOICE using API? I use the following `POST` method to create the new Customer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: {"code":4,"message":"Invalid value passed for JSONString"}
This is the error...If u have any other methods Just tell me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this following piece of code can serve your need.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    String url = "https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/contacts?authtoken=AUTHTOKEN&organization_id=ORGID";
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("contact_name", "Test");
    //You can add other JSONString params here.

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSONString", json.toString()));
    //You can add other params like JSONString here.

    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    String body = handler.handleResponse(response);

    System.out.println(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please ensure that the JSONString that you are providing is in the correct format?

Valid JSON -

```
{
"contact_name":"Sabari",
"company_name": "Bowman and Co",
"contact_persons": [
        {
          "salutation": "Mr.",
          "first_name": "Will",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "email": "willsmith@bowmanfurniture.com"
         }
 ]
}
```

You will face an error if it's not a well formed json format 
Example -

```
{customer_name=sabari,company_name=Bowman and Co}
```

Hope this helps.

Do let me know if you face any issues.

Sabari

Comment: I mentioned correct format of Json.Because it is valid.Just Check it in POSTMAN chrome app.It perfectly send my requet to URL and Customer Will be added Successfully.But,How to do in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Clearly mentions that the JSON you provide is invalid. You can use a JSONSimple library to may be create a simple JSON or GSON as  mentioned in the link below and give it a try. 
https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/contacts/#create-a-contact

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class ZOHOTestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/contacts?authtoken=xxxxxxxxxxx6&organization_id=xxxxxxxx";

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
//being lazy pick the JSON from a file :)
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\DevelopmentTools\\3.CODE\\invoice.json"));
/*
//You can create the JSON like this

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONObject zohoInvoiceRequest = new JSONObject();

        zohoInvoiceRequest.put("contact_name", "Bowman and Co");
        zohoInvoiceRequest.put("company_name", "Bowman and Co");
        zohoInvoiceRequest.put("payment_terms", new Integer(15));
        zohoInvoiceRequest.put("payment_terms", "Net 15");

        JSONObject billing_address = new JSONObject();
        billing_address.put("address", "4900 Hopyard Rd, Suite 310");
        billing_address.put("city", "Pleasanton");
        billing_address.put("state", "94588");
        billing_address.put("country", "USA");
        zohoInvoiceRequest.put("billing_address", billing_address);

        System.out.println(jsonObject.toJSONString());
*/
        url += "&JSONString=";
        url += URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toJSONString(),"UTF-8");

        System.out.println(url);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        // post.setEntity(new StringEn);
        // post.setEntity(new StringEntity("&JSONString=" +
        // jsonObject.toJSONString()));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    }
}
```

Response Code : HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 201 Created [Server: ZGS, Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 16:32:17 GMT, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Connection: keep-alive, Set-Cookie: edfb7d8656=ce40e27c37c608027f2a04de26189092; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, X-XSS-Protection: 1, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, Set-Cookie: zbcscook=1c083c08-9c4e-4210-9a70-b248751cf5a2; Path=/; Secure, Pragma: no-cache, Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A8CC1842C061BC3CA8FD333FEBB5823; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 1000, X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 7062, X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 991, Content-Disposition: attachment;, Allow: OPTIONS, POST, GET, DELETE, Set-Cookie: BuildCookie_632436810=2; Expires=Fri, 05-Aug-2016 16:37:17 GMT; Secure, BUILD_VERSION: Jul_28_2016_2_5435, CLIENT_BUILD_VERSION: Jul_28_2016_2_5435, SERVER_BUILD_VERSION: Aug_02_2016_5_4512/, Location: /api/v3/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx001, Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cache-Control: no-cache, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000] org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity@d6da883}

The file invoice.json is a copy paste of the JSON request in the URL (https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/contacts/#create-a-contact)

Comment: I mentioned correct format of Json.Because it is valid.Just Check it in POSTMAN chrome app.It perfectly send my requet to URL and Customer Will be added Successfully.But,How to do in JAVA

Comment: @MariSelvan , posted a working snip.Tested locally , works